# Doubt in the proof of Banach-Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

> **Theorem:** Let $V$ be a Banach Space and $W$ be a normed linear space. Let $I$ be an arbitrary indexing set and for each $i\in I$, let $T_i\in L(V,W)$. Then either,
>
> (1)there exists $M>0$ such that $\|T_i\|\le M$ for all $i\in I$ or
>
> (2) $\sup_{i\in I}$ $\|T_i(x)\|=\infty$, for all $x$ belonging to some dense $G_{\delta}$ set in $V$.

This is how the proof goes by,

For each $x$, define $\phi(x)=\sup_{i\in I}\|T_i(x)\|$

Define $V_n=\{x\in V| \;\phi(x)>n\}$.

$V_n$ is open for each $n$.

Assume now that there exists $N$ such that $V_N$ fails to be dense in $V$.

Then there exists $x_0\in V$ and $r>0$ such that $x+x_0\notin V_N$ if $\|x\|<r.$

This implies that $\phi(x+x_0)\le N$ for all such $x$ and so, for all $i\in I$
$\|T_i(x+x_0)\|\le N$.

Thus if $\|x\|\le r/2$, we have , for all $i\in I$, $\|T_i(x)\|\le \|T_i(x+x_0)\|+\|T_i(x_0)\|\le 2N$

> It follows from this that, for all $i\in I$,  $\|T_i\|\le \frac{4N}{r}$

I do not understand how the above highlighted argument holds. Can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: When you wrote the inequality "$\|T_i(x)\|\le \|T_i(x+x_0)\|+\|T_i(x_0)\|\le N$", did you actually mean to write $2N$ instead of $N$ on the RHS. (That would explain why it is $\frac{2N}{r/2}$ and not $\frac{N}{r/2}$.)

Comment: Oops! It was a typo, thanks for pointing it out @MartinSleziak

Comment: "$\sup_{i\in I}$ $\|T_i\|=\infty$, for all $x$"  that sentence does not make sense because there is no $x$ in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\|T_i\|
= \sup_{\|x\|\le 1}\|T_i(x)\|
= \sup_{\|x\|\le 1}\frac{2}{r}\left\|T_i\left(\frac{rx}{2}\right)\right\|
\le \frac{2}{r}2N = \frac{4N}{r},
\end{align*}
where the inequality follows from the previous line and the fact that $\|rx/2\|\le r/2$.